# Python/Json: How to format nested json string with **dict?

Tags: python, json, format

I have testdata read from excel and want it used to format a nested json string for request post body used, details as below:

```py
import json


kwargs = {"name": "testname", "device": {"plt": "dsk"}}

payload = """
{{
    "name": "{name}",
    "device": "{device}",
}}
"""

payload = json.loads(payload.format(**kwargs))
```

And the expected payload should be:

```py
{
    "name": "testname",
    "device": {"plt": "dsk"}
}
```

But there's error with `json.loads(payload.format(**kwargs))`, then how to format nested json string with **dict?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3HyA.png)

Comment: that is not the correct json format, please use a validator tool like [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)

Comment: Does `payload` contain keys other than those that are in `kwargs`?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the operation in steps to figure out what goes wrong.

```
kwargs = {"name": "testname", "device": {"plt": "dsk"}}

payload = """
{{
    "name": "{name}",
    "device": "{device}",
}}
"""

json_string = payload.format(**kwargs)

print(json_string)
```

gives

```
{
    "name": "testname",
    "device": "{'plt': 'dsk'}",
}
```

Notice the dictionary `{'plt': 'dsk'}` was stringified python-style before being interpolated into the payload string. This is not valid json -- the apostrophes need to be replaced with quotation  marks.

To get around this, I suggest you create a python dict that looks like `payload` and then convert *that* to a json string.

```
# Some preexisting dictionary
payload_dict = {"oldvalue": 0}

# Add values from kwargs
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    payload_dict[key] = value

# Dump it to json
payload = json.dumps(payload_dict, indent=4) # indent=4 is only for pretty-print
print(payload)
```

which gives the output:

```
{
    "oldvalue": 0,
    "name": "testname",
    "device": {
        "plt": "dsk"
    }
}
```

If `payload_dict` is identical to `kwargs`, then all you need to do is

```
payload = json.dumps(kwargs)
print(payload)
```

```
{
    "name": "testname",
    "device": {
        "plt": "dsk"
    }
}
```